# Is it possible to create custom annotations in adobe embed api

Tags: adobe-embed-api

Trying to change the title of the annotation menu and pop up from Add Sticky Note to something else, has anyone created custom anotations?

I need to create a custom menu item to create an annotation, is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking to add custom annotation ***types*** or just ***replace*** the current annotation UI? If you just want to replace the UI with one of your own design then, I can help with that and post some code as an answer. Currently, you cannot add custom annotation types... like a line or arrow or something.

Comment: Ho Joel, thanks for replying, we are needing to add a custom stamp annotation, so the UI would need to contain custom stamp buttons. These would just be location markers for inserting content, images, etc.

Comment: At this time custom annotations including stamp annotations cannot be added to the PDF via Embed API so the UI doesn't support the addition of these types of tools. I will add this as a feature request though because I'd love to have that feature as well. I've developed a lot of custom dynamic stamps for Acrobat so I know how popular stamps are.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API to work with annotations. This is documented here, https://opensource.adobe.com/pdfembed-sdk-docs/howtos_comments.html#annotations-api-overview. As I know SO frowns on posting just links, I'd suggest giving this a try and if it doesn't work, you can edit the question with a specific problem with the API. Let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: Cheers Raymond, the API is very useful thank you, but it seems the menu items on creating actual annotations is STATIC, I need to create a custom annotation, looks like PDF Tron is the only solution.